# Passing an array through jquery ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to turn form inputs into an array (input names as keys and values as values) inside of jquery using serializeArray()... then pass it to a php script via $jquery.ajax.. using the post method.

```
$(function () {
    $("#xbut").click(function () {
        var values = {};
        $.each($(':input').serializeArray(), function (i, field) {
            values[field.name] = field.value;
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ajax/NewClient.php',
            data: {
                clientdata: values
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

i had this working last night... but made some changes and now can't revert.  when i use the array conversion for data... i cannot find $_POST['clientdata'] in the NewClient.php.. it just isn't defined.  If I change my ajax data into a string... i can find whatever i post.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use `data: $('form').serialize()`?

Comment: Why would you need everything in an array, instead of them being a separate value in the `$_POST` array?

Comment: My php script needs an array and that should be much simpler to do in jquery than making a string passed by ajax into one....

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that

```
.serializeArray()
```

should be

```
.serialize()
```

---

```
$(function() {
    $("#xbut").click(function() {
        var values = {}; 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ajax/NewClient.php',
            data: { clientdata : $(":input").serialize() },
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: They are both valid options - `serializeArray` puts the data into an array, `serialize` puts it into a query-style string

Comment: Using this turns my post into a string.  Using this but with serializeArray passes an array with a nested array for each input.  I had it passing a one dimensional array with the code in the original question (as far as i know) last night.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your script and it seems to work -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#xbut").click(function() {
                var values = {};
                $.each($(':input').serializeArray(), function(i,field){
                    values[field.name] = field.value; 
                }); 
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'PHPPage3.php',
                    data: { clientdata : values },
                    success: function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
            return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <body>
    <input type="text" name="tester"/>     
    <input type="button"  value="x" id="xbut"/>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Then 'PHPPage3.php' is -

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['clientdata']['tester'];
?>
```

On clicking the button on the first page the value in the 'tester' field is alerted back.